# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' for a string array

Tags: c#, string, integer

I'm trying to do an assignment for my coding class and I'm quite new to this. My class wants someone to input 5 values into an array from user input. The statements MUST be in a while loop.

Here's my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] numbers = new string[6];
            int i = 1;
            while (i <= 5)
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter a number here:");
                numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                i++;
            }

        

        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs at

```
numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

I'm trying to convert the user input into an int value, but It doesn't let me. Any reason why? please let me know and understand I'm really new to this.

Comment: You have declared an array of _strings_ then you try to put into that array the result of the conversion of the Console.ReadLine (a string) to an int. Of course C# (a strongly typed language) doesn't allow you to do that. Declare your array as int not as strings. Consider also that if your user types something that is not a number Convert.ToInt32 crashes. You should use Int32.TryParse for conversion of user inputted numbers

Comment: Looks like you got the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67355200/can-some-help-me-out-im-stuck-my-code-needs-to-be-able-to-take-in-floating-point) (entering 5 values and converting) homework assignment? ;)

Comment: @MickyD How curious; same task and the same type of problem (wrong types).

Comment: @MickyD yup haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to convert an input which data type is a string to an int data type.
Change the numbers array data type from string to int.

```
int[] numbers = new int[6];
```

I would also add a check to see if the input from the user is indeed a number via Int32.TryParse.

This function will try to Convert the string (first argument) to a number in its 32-bit signed integer representation and returns a boolean value which indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

```
 string value = Console.ReadLine();
 int number;
 bool success = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
 if (success)
 {
    numbers.Add(number);
 }
```

Comment: Such an obvious thing, but I didn't think it haha. Thank you

Comment: No problem @H0tline (: Can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the Data type of your array is on type `string` and on your user input, you are trying to convert it as an `int` so you will definitely have an exception

Since you are using *"Please enter a number here:"* on your ouput, you can make the type of your array as an `int`

```
  int[] numbers = new int[6];
  int i = 1;
  while (i <= 5)
  {
      Console.Write("Please enter a number here:");
      numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      i++;
  }
```

Comment: If you really want to help then you should also explain how to solve the problem for user inserting a letter instead of a number.